# How can I cross lake tiles in As Far As The Eye?

Tags: as-far-as-the-eye

In my last game I had a corner of the map surrounded by water.

[image]

How can I cross these water tiles to explore the remaining ones ? (I want the research bonus for exploring the whole map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found 2 ways to cross the lakes:

First way is given as a tip on the map:

[image: transform lake tip]

By right clicking on a lake you can pay 80 wood to transform it into a bog.

[image: transform lake action]

Second way is more random: there is a trait that let you cross the water:

> Levitation: This pupil can walk on lakes

[image]